# Need to setup a google key for gmail inbox

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, google-api

I am using SOAP web-service to grab the gmail inbox. But, it asks me for setting a Google Key for respective API.

How to set up a google key for wsdl? Any Ideas?

I am connecting to the gmail API but, I am not able to get the response into my page.

**Code:-**

```
"<div>
<a href='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=954719584955.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://localhost/gmail&scope=https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/&response_type=code'> Retrieve your Google Mails using webservices.</a>
</div>"
```

It redirects to my page which is registered and not getting the google content what I requested.

**Code:-**

```
    $client_id='954719584955.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $client_secret='vyY-DRInNsofJL2MTmpaVRYP';
    $redirect_uri='https://localhost/gmail';
    $max_results = 200;

    $auth_code = $_GET["code"];

    function curl_file_get_contents($url)
    {
     $curl = curl_init();
     $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);   //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);    //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);   //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.    

     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);   //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.

     $contents = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     return $contents;
    }


$fields=array(
    'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
    'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
    'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
    'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
    'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
);
$post = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$post = rtrim($post,'&');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response =  json_decode($result);
$accesstoken = $response->access_token;

$url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/??max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
if((strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Authorization required'))>0) && (strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Error '))>0)) //At times you get Authorization error from Google.
{
    echo "<h2>OOPS !! Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>";
    exit();
}
```

Here is the complete code for gmail API.

Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: right now, I am able to retrieve all my google contacts using CURL and I am trying to get all my google mails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should visit [google apis console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). There you can register an application and set up apis you are going to use.

Comment: I didn't found any gmail like api's in that page. Though I have found an API key when I navigate through 'API Access', it referred to 'OAuth' web service. I just need to use SOAP service.

Comment: It is the same: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#gmail_inbox_feed

Comment: SOAP is a communication protocol. OAuth is a authentication method/pattern. You need to register an app, get OAuth tokens for it and sign each of your SOAP requests with it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know such things 'kgb'. I will try and get back to you later. Thank you!

Comment: I'm 70% done but, with one little exception. I am able to connect to the google api. But, it shows an error like, "response code is missing".

Comment: It is hard to say anything until you post full texts of both request and response.